# How to convert my server time to other country time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone, nsdate

I am getting time from server is `2016/07/19--12:20:00`
Now I have to change this time according to country.
For example If I am in Auckland then time has to like `2016/07/19--18:50:00`
I found so many solutions in stack overflow but I can't solve this.
Please help me

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY/MM/dd--HH:mm:ss"];
        NSDate* sourceDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:model.tripEndTime];
        NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
        NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
        NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
        NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;
        NSDate* destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate];
        NSDateFormatter* dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY/MM/dd--HH:mm:ss"];
        NSString* localTime = [dateFormat stringFromDate:destinationDate];
        NSLog(@"localTime:%@", localTime);
```

I tried with this code

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: Is the time from the server in GMT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert the server time to UTC time, then convert to local country time. Just write a separate method for this

```
 +(NSString*)convertLocaleTimeToChatTimeStampWithDateStr:(NSString  *)strDate
{
NSDateFormatter *df = [DateHelper getDefaultTimeFormatter];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:strDate];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, hh:mm a"];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
return [df stringFromDate:date];
}

+(NSDateFormatter*)getDefaultTimeFormatter
{
NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
return df;
}
```

hope this will solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: I think instead of directly setting the timezone wouldn't it be better to use the phone's timezone? the only issue is if the phone didn't switch to the current timezone

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use server timestamp. After getting timestamp convert it according to timezone

Comment: Can you give example @ios Developer

Comment: NSString * timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

Comment: This is for getting current timestamp and for getting server timestamp you have to write the code in server side

Comment: @iosDeveloper you didn't answer the question. I think the question was valid.